# Generic typing a hashmap with dynamic key and T array

Tags: typescript

I try to create a strong typing interface for an hashmap in typescript.

The hashmap contains a key with a dynamic string name. And a `values` which contains an array of Generic type.

I tried to use the following interface:

```
export interface DynamicHashmap<T> {
  [dynamicKey: string]: string;
  values: T[];
}
```

but it won't compile and keep complaining:

> [ts] Property 'values' of type 'T[]' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.

An example of generated value corresponding to this type, which groups values depending on an object attribute (here `User.group`). The `dynamicKey` is here resolved to `group`.

```
const user1: User = { id: 'userValue1', group: 'someGroupId' };
const user2: User = { id: 'userValue2', group: 'someGroupId' }; 
const result = {
  group: 'someGroupId',
  values: [
    { id: 'userValue1', group: 'someGroupId' },
    { id: 'userValue2', group: 'someGroupId' }
  ]
}
```

I guess the static `values` interfere with the dynamic key.

How can I achieve the strong typing we are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when I hear "dynamic" I try to understand if that means "known only at runtime" or "known at compile time but has different values in different locations".  If it's the former then you have to use very wide types (like the string-indexed thing you're talking about)... if it's the latter, then you can sometimes use generics to express a narrower type.  For example, in your case:

```
type DynamicHashMap<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> & {values: T[]};
```

or

```
type DynamicHashMap<T, K extends keyof T> = { 
  [P in K | 'values']: P extends K ? T[K] : T[] 
};
```

is generic both in `T`, and in `K`, a key of the `T` type.  You could use type inference to instantiate both `T` and `K`, like so:

```
// for example
function makeDynamicHashMap<T, K extends keyof T>(
  key: K, 
  value: T[K], 
  values: T[]
): DynamicHashMap<T, K> {
  return { [key]: value, values: values.filter(v => v[key] === value) } as any;
}

const result = makeDynamicHashMap("group", "someGroupId", [user1, user2]);
result.group; // string
result.values; // User[]
```

So `result` is inferred to be type `DynamicHashMap<User, "group">`.  Does that help?  Good luck!

Comment: it is indeed the second circumstance: it's known at compile time but different values depending on context. I tried your both types and it works as expected. Is one of the two methods recommended over the other?

Answer (score 5):

The correct interface is this

```
export interface DynamicHashmap<T> {
  [key: string]: string | T[];
  values: T[];
}
```

This is because, `[key: string]` represents a signature of *all* the keys. That is why it is called *index signature*.

You might not be very satisfied with such interface, that's why you should reconsider it to be something else like:

```
export interface DynamicHashmap<T> {
  dynamicKey: string;
  dynamicValue: string;
  values: T[];
}
```

Comment: Why do we have to use `string | T[]` for `dynamicKey` value?

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy or to put is simpler if you access `result['values']` the result will not be `string`

Comment: Titian is correct. Also see the new updates to my answer

Comment: You can use an intersection type to allow what you want, but you will not be able to use a simple object literal to create such an object (you can with `Object.assign`) and it's not exactly consistent (this is why the compiler is fighting you on it). `export type DynamicHashmap<T> = {
      [dynamicKey: string]: string;
    } & {
      values: T[];
    }`